# Retain first original character when using Regex Replace?

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

Here is VB.Net Regex code to replace text unless that text is preceeded or followed by a letter:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
​
Public Module Module1

Public Sub Main()

Dim strProhibitedWord As String = "fox"
Dim strProhibitedWordEnclosed As String = "(?<!\p{L})" + strProhibitedWord + "(?!\p{L})"
Dim strSentence1 As String = "The quick brown Fox jumped over the foxy sheep to see his fox friend."
Dim optOptions1 As RegexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
Dim strResult As String = Regex.Replace(strSentence1, strProhibitedWordEnclosed, "***", optOptions1)

Console.WriteLine(strResult)

End Sub

End Module
```

The code gives the result:

```
The quick brown *** jumped over the foxy sheep to see his *** friend.
```

What code change could give the following result (e.g., show the first original character followed by the remaining character mask):

```
The quick brown F** jumped over the foxy sheep to see his f** friend.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the first word letter with a capturing group:

```vb
Dim strProhibitedWordEnclosed As String = "(?<!\p{L})(" & strProhibitedWord.Substring(0,1) & ")" & strProhibitedWord.Substring(1) & "(?!\p{L})"
```

Then, you need to replace with `$1**`:

```vb
Dim strResult As String = Regex.Replace(strSentence1, strProhibitedWordEnclosed, "$1**", optOptions1)
```

See the [VB.NET demo online](https://ideone.com/SesHHV):

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
 
Public Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim strProhibitedWord As String = "fox"
        Dim strProhibitedWordEnclosed As String = "(?<!\p{L})(" & strProhibitedWord.Substring(0,1) & ")" & strProhibitedWord.Substring(1) & "(?!\p{L})"
        Dim strSentence1 As String = "The quick brown Fox jumped over the foxy sheep to see his fox friend."
        Dim optOptions1 As RegexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
        Dim strResult As String = Regex.Replace(strSentence1, strProhibitedWordEnclosed, "$1**", optOptions1)
 
        Console.WriteLine(strResult)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Output:

```
The quick brown F** jumped over the foxy sheep to see his f** friend.
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how you were able to retain the case of the first original character 'f' or 'F', whatever it was in the sentence, when you were taking the strProhibitedWord.Substring(0,1), since strProhibitedWord As String = "fox" (all lower). It seemed to work though in your online sample.

Comment: @user1946932 `(f)ox` pattern used with a regex compiled with `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` matches `fox` in any case while capturing the first letter into Group 1. In the Group 1, the letter is in the case as was found in text, thus, `$1` replaces with the letter in the found case.